# Change DirectLine secret dynamically on client side

Tags: javascript, botframework

The bot is set up on page load, however we receive a secret from an application and want to place the secret in the bot.

Here is the current setup:

```
const initialBotConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({ secret: 'secret1', });

initialBotConnection.activity$
    .filter(activity => activity.type === "event")
    .subscribe(activity => changeBotConnection(activity.value))

const changeSecret = () => {
    initialBotConnection
        .postActivity({
            type: "event",
            value: "GetSecret",
            from: { id: "me" }
        })
        .subscribe(id => console.log("success"));
}
changeSecret();

function changeBotConnection(secret) {
    if (secret != "GetSecret") {
        console.log("secret is " + secret);
        initialBotConnection.secret = secret;
    }
    if (secret == "NONE")
        chatOffline();
}

BotChat.App({
    user: { id: 'You' },
    bot: { id: 'botName' },
    resize: 'detect',
    botConnection: initialBotConnection
}, document.getElementById("bot"));
```

Is it possible to reinitialize the chat? We have an initateChat function, however placing the BotChat.App code doesn't work, in fact it breaks the bot. It seems like the BotChat.App code needs to be outside a function?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving a token instead? It's not possible at this time to change your Direct Line *secret* programmatically, but if you can use your secret to retrieve new tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Steven. I am using DirectLineJS and cannot find any examples of fetching a token from a secret with this framework, do you know if there are any functions within DirectLineJS which can do this?

Comment: This isn't in DirectlineJS, but an example of the API in use to generate a new token can be found here in this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-DirectLineWebSockets/README.md#code-highlights).